# How can I see the time and charges of my latest Skype call?

Tags: skype

How can I see the time and charges of my latest Skype call?

You would think Skype would make this easy...but no.  I sometimes see the duration but never the charges.

Comment: Please use descriptive question titles!

Answer (score 0):

The Skype website has an [account usage](https://secure.skype.com/account/usage) section which contains this information.